# Add QRectGraphicsItem

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

I'm trying to learn Qt by developing a simple GUI. Part of what I need to do is add a rectangle to one of three QGraphicsView areas I have made. I used the following code

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow){
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QGraphicsRectItem rect;
    rect.setRect(10,10,10,10);
    ui->graphicsView->scene()->addRect(rect.rect());
}
```

However while this compiles just fine, my program does not run at all, in fact upon reaching the last line it immediately exits, does anyone know what the issue could be? (Apologies for formatting, first time poster)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a scene to your `QGraphicsView` first:

```
ui->graphicsView->setScene(new QGraphicsScene);
```

Right now `ui->graphicsView->scene()` is returning a null pointer.

`QGraphicsView::scene()`: [*Returns a pointer to the scene that is currently visualized in the view. If no scene is currently visualized, 0 is returned.*](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#scene)

Also, instead of creating a `QGraphicsRectItem` and using its `rect()` method to return a `QRect` object that you will use in `QGraphicsScene::addRect()`, you should just create a `QRect` object and use that:

```
QRect rect(10,10,10,10);
ui->graphicsView->scene()->addRect(rect);
```